# How to level concrete floor that is chipped and has left over thinset

Tags: concrete, floor

I removed some tile from a 10' by 15' section of my basement floor.  As I was removing the tile, much of the concrete chipped away leaving low areas.  Other areas have thin set remaining in the shape of the trowel grooves.  And yet some areas are at the original level of the concrete floor.  I want to eventually lay down some type of laminate hardwood.

How do I fill the low spots and knock down the high spots so it's level?

Comment: pictures would help

Answer (score 1):

A silicon carbide grinding block (gray block with grooves, red handle, is the form I usually see - about 5x9x2 inches to start with, thinner as you use it and it wears down) is how you knock down the high spots.

[image]

After you do that you can use some type of levelling compound for the low areas - normal cement won't be happy in such a thin layer.